# Error when returning model after updating many to many relationship in Laravel API request

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-artisan

I'm setting up a Laravel API and I'm dealing with the User model.

It has two relationships:
- One-to-many relationship: Role
- Many-to-many relationship: Teams

When I update one user through an API request, it won't send back the updated many-to-many relationship.

This is the updating function right now:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::with('role', 'teams')->findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    if ($request->teams) {
        $user->teams()->sync($request->teams);
    }
    if ($request->role) {
        $user->role()->associate(Role::findOrFail($request->role));
    }
    $user->save();
    return response()->json($user, 200);
}
```

I'm sending a User object:

```
User {
  email: "admin@admin.com"
  first_name: "Admin"
  teams: [4,5,6]
  ...
}
```

It updates correctly in the database, but the returning object from the request contains no value in the teams array:

```
User {
  email: "admin@admin.com"
  first_name: "Admin"
  teams: []
  ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe something like `$user->teams()->fresh()` ? Never tried these but just guessing.

Comment: Hmm never heard of that fresh method, where do you think I should add it? @vivek_23

Comment: After you do `$user->save()`, you could do `$user = $user->fresh()` to better refresh the entire model itself.

Comment: Or better directly do `$user->refresh();` after `$user->save()` so that the same model instance is refreshed.

Comment: Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models (scroll down a bit).

Comment: Thank you a lot! Refreshing the model instance after saving it solved it @vivek_23

Comment: Glad to see that working.